# Rails: Ajax for Like Button and Updating Like Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am able to update the like and unlike button via ajax, but I am not able to update the like count.

Post `has_many` likes

likes_controller.rb

```
  def create    
    @like = Like.new(:post_id => params[:post_to_be_liked])
    if @like.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: "Liked!"}
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

view.html.erb

```
<% @post = user.posts.first %>
<div id="send_like_for_<%= @post.id %>">
     <% if @post.is_liked?(@post, current_user)%>
    <%= render 'unlike'%>
     <%else%>
        <%= render 'like'%>
     <%end%>
</div>

<div id="liked_<%= @post.id %>" %>
    <%= render 'liked_users'%>
</div>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#send_like_for_<%= params[:post_to_be_liked]%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unlike')) %>")
$("#liked_<%= params[:post_to_be_liked]%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/liked_users')) %>")
```

_like.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "LIKE", likes_path(:post_to_be_liked => @post.id), remote: true, :method=>:post %>
```

_unlike.html.erb

```
<span> UNLIKE </span>
```

_liked_users.html.erb

```
<%= "#{@post.likes.length} like this" %>
```

The like/unlike functionality works just fine and when someone likes the post the button changes to Unlike. But the like count doesn't increase.

Comment: You have to update your '@post' object, because it contains the likes that are being stored earlier.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But why are you doing this in your view?

```
<% @post = user.posts.first %>
```

It will update only your first post always. I can't understand.

Try with this:

_liked_users.html.erb

```
<%= @updated_post = Post.where(id: @post.id) %>    
<%= "#{@updated_post.likes.length} like this" %>
```

or

```
<%= @post.reload %>    
<%= "#{@post.likes.length} like this" %>
```

Edit (Try to build your like this):

```
def create
    @post = Post.where(id: params[:post_to_be_liked])    
    @like = @post.likes.build(:post_id => @post.id)
    if @like.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: "Liked!"}
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Its because I am only displaying the users first post (the most recent) in the users index action. Let me try this.

Comment: Both don't work. Does nothing. It even stops the like/unlike functionality

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to do this

```
@post = user.posts.first
```

after save in your controller and remove <% @post = user.posts.first %> from erb file and if it is not possible then initialize @post in your controller#create

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_to_be_liked])
```

Comment: I am iterating through users. So in order to find the posts of each user, I have to keep it in the view. I'm actually doing @users.each.do |user| before `<% @post = user.posts.first %>` in my view

Comment: The issue is @post variable is not defined when you create like. You can do this in your likes#create @ post = Post.find(params[:post_to_be_liked])